# how to count the number of user inputs in Python

Tags: python, count

Im having loads of trouble trying to count the number of guesses in this after you find the number.

```
def play_game():
    print("Enter the upper limit for the range of numbers: ")
    limit = int(input())
    number = random.randint(1, limit)
    print("I'm thinking of a number from 1 to " + str(limit) + "\n")
    while True:
        guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
        if guess < number:
            print("Too low.")
        elif guess > number:
            print("Too high.")
        elif guess == number:
            print("You guessed it in " + str(count) + " tries.\n")
            return
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def play_game():
    print("Enter the upper limit for the range of numbers: ")
    limit = int(input())
    number = random.randint(1, limit)
    print("I'm thinking of a number from 1 to " + str(limit) + "\n")
    count = 1 #new line
    while True:
        guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
        if guess < number:
            print("Too low.")
        elif guess > number:
            print("Too high.")
        elif guess == number:
            print("You guessed it in " + str(count) + " tries.\n")
        count = count+1 #new line
```

Answer (score 0):

start with a variable to store the number of guesses

```
...
count = 0
...
```

then increment it on every guess

```
...
guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
count += 1
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `count` as 1 and `increment` on each `loop`.

```
import random
def play_game():

    print("Enter the upper limit for the range of numbers: ")
    limit = int(input())
    number = random.randint(1, limit)
    print("I'm thinking of a number from 1 to " + str(limit) + "\n")
    count = 1
    while True:
        guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
        if guess < number:
            print("Too low.")
        elif guess > number:
            print("Too high.")
        elif guess == number:
            print("You guessed it in " + str(count) + " tries.\n")
            return
        count+=1
play_game()
```

An example output:

```
Enter the upper limit for the range of numbers: 
10
I'm thinking of a number from 1 to 10

Your guess: 3
Too low.
Your guess: 7
Too low.
Your guess: 9
Too low.
Your guess: 10
You guessed it in 4 tries.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
highest = 10

answer = random.randrange(1,highest)
guess = 0
count = 0

print("please guess a number between 1 and {}".format(highest))

while guess != answer:
    guess = int(input())
    if count == 4:
        exit(print("you exceeded number of chances"))
    if guess == answer:
        print("well done you have guessed it correctly and the answer is 
                {}".format(guess))
        break
    else:
        if guess < answer:
            print("please guess higher")
        else:
            print("please guess lower")
        count = count +1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only answers always benefit from an explanation of how they answer the question.